# Runtime Error on _gdal.Driver_Create with no explanation

Tags: gdal

I'm creating a tiff file using this code:

```
        coverage_image = gdal.GetDriverByName('GTiff').Create(
            filename,
            self.match_data['width'],
            self.match_data['height'],
            4,
            gdal.GDT_Byte,
            options=tiff_options
        )
```

This code has always worked. Out of the blue, I start getting this:

```
    coverage_image = gdal.GetDriverByName('GTiff').Create(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/osgeo/gdal.py", line 1849, in Create
    return _gdal.Driver_Create(self, *args, **kwargs)
RuntimeError
```

No explanation is given except for `RuntimeError`

Answer (score 0):

This forum post tipped me off to the answer:
https://issues.qgis.org/issues/21958

This occurs when `filename` already exists.
(In my case, the existing `filename` was also of a completely different format, and erroneously labelled as a `tiff` file).